# Django Template Form rendering Dropdown List does not get populated

Tags: django

Having a Template view which gets rendered with the form processor; all values get filled perfectly int the respective fields except the Dropdowns.

On all Dropdown-Lists the *selected* Value is placed on the first item of the Dropdown, not on the one which is in the Database.

How it looks, when rendered:

```html
<select name="catmedia" class="form-control" placeholder="catmedia" id="id_catmedia">
  <option value="" selected="">None</option>

  <option value="film">Film</option>

  <option value="serie">Serie</option>

  <option value="doku">Doku</option>
```

the code from above should look like:

```html
<select name="catmedia" class="form-control" placeholder="catmedia" id="id_catmedia">
  <option value="" >None</option>

  <option value="film">Film</option>

  <option value="serie" selected>Serie</option>

  <option value="doku">Doku</option>
```

How can this be fixed? The **selected** part should be inserted at the right place, it does not yet. Why is it not populated correctly? What did I overlook?

Here are the related code parts.

View:

```
class mForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': field,
            })
  class Meta:
    model = Mediadb
```

Model:

```
catmedia_ = (
    ('','None'),
    ('film','Film'),
    ('serie','Serie'),
    ('doku','Doku'),
 )

 catmedia  = models.CharField(max_length=34,blank=True,choices=catmedia_, default='')
```

Template:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
           {{ field }}
        </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The Django Version used is:  3.8 (maybe this is a flaw in this  version? / can it be confirmed that the rendering of Dropdown selected values is working in this version?)

Comment: Did you check the database entry via `python manage.py shell` really not having `serie` stored? Because maybe the mistake already happens when you store your object.

Comment: The value is `stored`, in other views it is clear to see. Its just not rendering in the formview.

Answer (score 1):

I sense multiple reasons for this:

**First:** Specifying the `default` like you did has secondary influence on the form. When you pass the `initial` parameter to the form somewhere in your view (you did not provide the code for the views) then the `default` gets overwritten by `initial`.

```py
catmedia  = models.CharField(max_length=34,blank=True,choices=catmedia_, default='')
```

**Second:** Your `__init__` method might also pass the empty string value `''` to the `ChoiceField`. Inside of that `__init__` method you want to differentiate between the different types of fields. Most likely you will encounter that `form-control` (when it is bootstrap) does not look as cool as `form-select` on all your select widgets.

```py
class BaseForm(forms.BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            if isinstance(field.widget, widgets.RadioSelect):
                continue
            elif isinstance(field.widget, widgets.Select):
                field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-select'})
                continue
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})


class mForm(forms.ModelForm, BaseForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mediadb

        # usually you define your placeholders specifically like this
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Thorben'})
        }
```

Above setup allows you to inherit all of your forms from `BaseForm`. So you don't have to implement this bootstrap thing to every single form.
You can still implement the for loop to above version of `mForm`.

**Long story short - Copy paste**

```
class mForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            if isinstance(self.fields[field].widget, widgets.Select):
                continue
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': field,
            })

  class Meta:
    model = Mediadb
```

Let me know if you have questions.

## Edit:

I gave it a second thought and I think you are just confusing `placeholder` with `initial`. If you really want to have static placeholders (they are usually grey, static and vanish if you click the field), then specify them in the `Meta` class as I showed earlier. If you simply want to have your form prefilled with the values from database, then just erase your entire **init** because this is the default of django.

Comment: **@second**

Including the `BaseForm` in `forms.ModelForm` is helpfull, didn't know that it can be used like that; thx

**confusing placeholder**: 

The `placeholders` here where used as `placeholders` not as `initials`. Code was a leftover from another place and are not used in this view so much; thanks for mentioning. 

You had some usefull informations, but

**the initial Problem** with `not provisioning the data fill from DBMS in the Dropdown selected` was not solved with this, unfortunately. I did not get an idea yet how to solve it either. All other values work, not Dropdown.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the view that stores the model and displays mentioned form (for update or whatever reason)?